# Dart - true and false are both compile-time constant and why it doesn't changes state?

Tags: dart

```
num point = 100;
bool fail = (point < 75) ? true : false;
print(fail); // false

point = 50;
print(fail); // false
```

I've changed `point` values but why `fail` doesn't change it values? although it satisfied the condition.

Please help me describe this problem

Thanks.

Comment: Is it because they're both constant? so their state doesn't change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is the value of `fail` (the variable) are being evaluated at the point of declaration. So we are calculating `(point < 75) ? true : false` and the value are saved into the variable of `fail`.

The variable is therefore not defined as a function but instead a specific value at the given time it was defined.

If you instead want `fail` to be defined as a method which can be evaluated multiple times you can do something like this:

```
void main() {
  num point = 100;
  bool Function() fail = () => (point < 75) ? true : false;
  print(fail()); // false

  point = 50;
  print(fail()); // true
}
```

Normally you want to pack this kind of logic inside a class like this:

```
class OurClass {
  num point;

  OurClass(this.point);

  bool get fail => (point < 75) ? true : false;
}

void main() {
  OurClass oClass = OurClass(100);
  print(oClass.fail); // false

  oClass.point = 50;
  print(oClass.fail); // true
}
```

So here we can define a `get` method which act like a variable but where we can evaluate the value each time we try to get it. So here we can define `fail` as the value returned from evaluating `(point < 75) ? true : false;`.

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't think to make it a one-liner function before haha. Thanks for your explanation